Google Calendar API seems to ignore resource ACLs when event is created programmatically
I have a service account for my GWS instance with full admin rights, and I use this client to make an API call to add an event to an organizer user's calendar, with a resource (room) added which this user is not allowed to book.
When using the native Google Calendar, this user will get an error when attempting to book that room (or rather, the room will decline).
But when I make an API call using my service account on behalf of this user, the resource accepts.
I would have thought that even though the event is created in the organizer user's calendar using an admin account, the resource would still respect ACLs for the organizer (especially since this is done asynchronously, I would have thought that resource would not even know HOW the event was created, just who the organizer is?), but it does not look that way. The resource accepts regardless of which organizer I create the event on behalf of.
How can I programmatically add an event for an organizer user where the resource accepts/declines according to the ACLs set up for that resource?
Example:

Room R1 is set up so that user U1 may book R1, but user U2 may not.
When U2 books R1 through calendar.google.com, R1 declines.
When I make an API call to create an event in U2's calendar, specifying R1 as the resource, R1 accepts.

Using calendar_v3 SDK from Node.JS:
  const {data: newEvent} = await calendar.events.insert({
    auth,
    quotaUser: '<u2-calendar-id>',
    calendarId: '<u2-calendar-id>,
    requestBody: event
  });

  // Wait a while and let resource respond
  // event.attendees now looks like this
  // attendees: [
  //   ...
  //   {
  //      "email": "<retracted>@resource.calendar.google.com",
  //      "displayName": "<retracted>",
  //      "resource": true,
  //      "responseStatus": "accepted"
  //   }
  // ]

